# How to add and delete widget dynamically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> Here I added `Stack widget` in `scaffold` body. I added full screen image as background image and set `edit` `text` `widget` functionality on `image`.
>
> I want to add `Multiple` `Text` `Widget` with `delete` and `add` `widget` functionality on `button click` in `flutter`. I mean when I Press on any particular `Text widget` it become `enable` and if I press on `delete Icon`, this particular `selected` `widget` `delete` on the `stack widget`.
>
> How it could be possible in `flutter`? Any suggestion for it or I should use any other `widget` rather than `Stack widget` for this functionality.